# difference between given dates

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have a sqlce database table that I am entering data every day.

```
Date          No      Meter_1     Meter_2    Meter_3
12-05-2010    1       1234        3456       4567
12-05-2010    2       3423        4567       0987
13-05-2010    1       2345        7654       7654
13-05-2010    2       7676        8765       5643
14-05-2010    1       2345        7654       7654
14-05-2010    2       7676        8765       5643
15-05-2010    1       2345        7654       7654
15-05-2010    2       7676        8765       5643
```

and I would like to find difference between given 2 dates with datetimepicker and display them in datagrid. Example: If I select Dates between 15th and 12th. Function has to subtract  12th meter values from 15th meter values. It was easy when i was dealing in Access with queries. But I can't do in VB.net. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks to every one

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of what you are trying to achieve? I couldn't understand it you want to subtract from Meter_1 submitted on 12.05 the value Meter_1 submitted on 15.05 and if it matters the No value somehow?

Comment: Actually I am trying to find daily usage of power but sometimes my managers need certain dates because of activities in organization. For example : I just want to find between 12-05-2010 and 15-05-2010 power usage. So in Meter_1 I have to find value for device No_1 "7676-1234 = 6442" Meter_2 "8765-3456 = 5309".

I hope that this can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can write queries against SQLCe so you could continue doing it that way. Otherwise, you can use SqlCeDataReader to retrieve all the data you need from the database (for example any records from the 12th and 15th), cache them in some list or something if needed for easier processing, process the data as needed (subtracting etc) then just add the data in the list to your grid.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader%28VS.80%29.aspx) for a sample of using SqlCeDataReader.